# Elastic Beanstalk Node.js Start Command

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to build a node.js app in Elastic Beanstalk using a different start command from the norm. We have a web app, and a worker app. Normally we just use app.js or server. js as our start for the app, and this works well. But we want to have a different start file for each app. I could use app.js for one, and server.js for the other, but this is not clear enough for me, and there is potential for error down the road. In addition, I'm supposed to be able to specify a different start file. So I have appQueue.js. In the beanstalk console, I have specified: appQueue.js, /appQueue.js, ./appQueue.js, /var/app/current/appQueue.js. The first two, the nodejs log says it's not found. Second two, I get permission denied. Has anyone been able to do this, and what is the format? I'm going to put a ticket in with AWS, but Elastic Beanstalk support is generally not even close to the 24 hour window they promise for support.

Comment: This isn't a programming question or a question about tools used for programming, so it is off topic. That said, this is a relatively easy thing to do. in the web console, after you click on your application, go to `Configuration -> Software Configuration` and change the node command. I use `npm start` and then define how i want my app to start in my package.json. You could also change this through the command line by storing the current configuration, modifying it, and then applying it.

Comment: I would say it's semantics. We are building this using batch files, using grunt and node commands, so I would say its programming, and I'm trying to figure out what to specify. But we also have a single package.json file, and want to keep it that way, so don't want to alter it or copy it. I could just copy a new app.js file into place, also. But I should be able to do this.

Comment: you should specify a single command that will start your application the way you want it to start. If that means executing a batch file, then execute a batch file.